# Python Click show version of module in help page

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I'm working on a command-line interface using click and I want to display the version of the package on the help page. As click auto-generates the help page I don't know, how to realize that. Any suggestions?

The version is specified in the packages `__init__.py` as `__version__` variable.

click: 7.x
Python: 3.6.3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For all of you, who have the same issue: click didn't solved the issue by now. I wrote an article revealing a pretty nice workaround using decorators. You can find the article on Medium: https://medium.com/@DahlitzF/customize-click-help-page-e302a6758d09?source=friends_link&sk=cedbe92fcff667e7b4574c1b450325ec

Answer (score 2):

Why does this not work?

```
@click.command()
def version():
    click.echo('Version: ' + __version__)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The solution you provided enables an additional command, that allows me to write `tool version` resulting in the displaying of the version number. What I want to achieve is, that a user can type `tool --help` and the auto-generated help page by click displays the version number first, followed by all of the help texts as usual.

Comment: To have it show up in the help page, add documentation under your main function: def main(args):"""Tool Version 8""" and it will show up in the help page

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
@click.group(help="""
This is mytool version {0}, a command-line tool for ...
""".format(__version__))
def main():
    pass

main.add_command(mycommand)
...
```